# Questions on vim-addon-manager

Tags: vim

I am using [this addon manager for vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2905). After installation, I can install scripts like [taglist.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273), but I can't install the script [octave.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3600): vim-addon-manager complained that `No repository location info known for plugin octave`.

According to [this page](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager-known-repositories), I ran `:call vam#install#LoadKnownRepos()`, but vim complained that there are not enough arguments for the function.

Can anyone give hints for me? Thank you.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Because there are several vim scripts for octave so one have to press 'tab' after typing 'octave' to view the candidates and decide which one is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nano can extended to highlight octave code.

```
~/.nanorc
# Octave syntax colors
syntax "octave" "\.m$" "\.octaverc$"

# keywords
color brightyellow "(case|catch|do|else(if)?|for|function|if|otherwise|switch|try|until|unwind_protect(_cleanup)?|vararg(in|out)|while)"
color brightyellow "end(_try_catch|_unwind_protect|for|function|if|switch|while)?"
color magenta "(break|continue|return)"

# storage-type
color green "(global|persistent|static)"
# data-type
color green "(cell(str)?|char|double|(u)?int(8|16|32|64)|logical|single|struct)"

# embraced
color brightred start="\(" end="\)"  # this line needs to be fixed to work properly in all cases
color blue start="\[|\{" end="\]|\}"

# strings
color yellow ""(\\.|[^\"])*"|'(\\.|[^\"])*'"

# comments
color brightblue "#.*|%.*"
```

read the [Octave Wiki](http://www.octave.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page).